# File size is 0 only for videos in Ionic on iOS 13.2 when selecting videos from Photo Library

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ios13.2

In my Ionic3 application I am calculating file size as follows.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="file" accept="*" (change)="onSelect($event)">
  <button ion-button (click)="calcSize()">calculate size</button>
</div>
<p>Size: {{ size }}</p>
```

**TS**

```
  file: File;
  size: number;

  onSelect(event: any) {

    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
  calcSize() {

    this.size = this.file.size;
  }
```

Above code is working perfectly on all the Android devices and iOS devices below iOS 13.2.

But **when selecting videos from Photo Library on iOS devices with greater than 13.2, the `size` is 0 only for video files**.

But **when selecting videos from iCloud Drive works fine.**

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Find issue on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qdxtyw).**

Comment: It seems a bug to me, have you reported to the proper repo in github?

Comment: @ ZetaPR thanks yes i reported to ionic repo. is there any repo to report

Comment: I have seen the bug reported and moved to the new Ionic repo. For anyone who wants to follow it: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/1077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling more than 7 days finding a solution for this. I am posting my findings as an answer because it will help someone who is facing this issue.

Actually my purpose was uploading file with other data to a **`Rest API`**. Those functionality failed only on **`iOS`** devices with version **13.2**. I could not find a solution for that and I decided to change whole implementation. Then I used **[Camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)** plugin and **[File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)** plugin to select videos from the Photo Library. That implementation is also has the same issue only on **`iOS`** devices with version **13.2**.

When using **`readAsDataURL(path, file)`**,**`readAsArrayBuffer(path, file)`** or **`readAsBinaryString(path, file)`** methods in **[File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)** plugin on selected video file using **[Camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)** plugin it was giving **`FileError 1`**(not found error).

The issue was in **[Camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)** plugin. The reason for this error is **photo library asset urls being invalidated on iOS 13**. There is a **[Git Hub Issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/346)** for this.

I found a temporary fix for this problem on **[This Link](https://github.com/kkabell/cordova-plugin-camera/commit/b1b0c9499b6b5c18d109671967e1218e05428e0a)**.

I manually edited **`src/ios/CDVCamera.h`** and **`src/ios/CDVCamera.m`** in **`platforms/ios`** as follows.

**CDVCamera.h**

```
@property (strong) CDVCameraPicker* pickerController;
@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *metadata;
@property (strong) NSDictionary *latestMediaInfo;// Newly added line
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong) NSData* data;
```

**CDVCamera.m**

```
__weak CDVCameraPicker* cameraPicker = (CDVCameraPicker*)picker;
__weak CDVCamera* weakSelf = self;

self.latestMediaInfo = info;// Newly added line

dispatch_block_t invoke = ^(void) {
    __block CDVPluginResult* result = nil;
```

**Hope this helps someone facing this issue.**

Answer (score 1):

I think its not an ionic bug. Specification says the following:

> On getting, **conforming user agents** must return the total number of
>   bytes

https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/

Seems to be an ios bug.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am offering bounty to you.